# Reflect on Time type in go

Tags: reflection, struct, go

I am trying to write a csv parser using the example provided [here](https://gist.github.com/stevedonovan/1422274). It works great for all native types but I am having trouble with any structs that contain a timestamp of type time.Time. It exits with an error of "cannot convert this type".

**This is the code.**

```
//For each field in a given struct...
    //Get a field
    val := sv.Field(i)
    // this is necessary because Kind can't tell 
    // distinguish between a primitive type
    // and a type derived from it. We're looking 
    // for a Value interface defined on
    // the pointer to this value
    _, ok := val.Addr().Interface().(Value)
    if ok {
        val = val.Addr()
        kind = value_k
    } else {
        switch Kind {
        case reflect.Int, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int8, 
             reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
            kind = int_k
        case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint8, 
             reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
            kind = uint_k
        case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
            kind = float_k
        case reflect.String:
            kind = string_k
        default:
                  // Kind is Struct here
            kind = value_k
            _, ok := val.Interface().(Value)
            if !ok {
                err = os.NewError("cannot convert this type ")
                this = nil
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

What this code does is take an interface and a reader. It attempts to match the field headers in the reader (csv file) with field names in the interface. It also reflects on the interface (struct) and collects positional a type information for later setting the fields in the iterator. It is this step that is failing for non-native types.

I've tried a few methods to work around this but the only thing that seems to work is changing the timestamp to a string. I am undoubtedly missing something and would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What is it that is actually throwing the error?

Comment: @JimB I added the code with some sparse comments.

Comment: Please make a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. In your code you have a "csv" package which doesn't exist in the stdlib, you have relative imports which you should not use, and `os.Error` which doesn't exist (well, technically it did, but not since go1 was released).

Comment: `time.Time` is a implemented as a struct, it does not implement your `Value` interface... no where in your code do you handle it so why would you expect your code to magically work with `time.Time`??

Comment: BTW, since CSV is a text format, instead of making your own `Value` interface why not use [`encoding.TextMarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler) and [`encoding.TextUnmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextUnmarshaler)? A side effect of doing that would be `time.Time` (which implements both) would just work.

Comment: @DaveC It's not actually my code, I was implementing another example. But now I see the issue as you have pointed out. I had inadvertently overlooked it. Thank you.